# Implementations of the Eisenstat-trick for SSOR

Tags: software, preconditioning, conjugate-gradient

Where can I find a source code for the SSOR method with Eisenstat's trick?

The [original paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/0902001) includes pseudo code but also seems to have minor typos. For that reason, I would be very happy to see an implementation somewhere. Unfortunately, I haven't any in the common libraries (perhaps the code is hidden to deep).